# Как закомментировать несколько строк в Emacs Lisp?

Tags: lisp, emacs

Вообще хочется комментировать сбалансированные скобочные выражения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(в lisp комментарии начинаются с ; И это не будет прочитано транслятором.
  (а вот это
    (будет)))

;;; комментарий к файлу

;; комментарий к функции

; комментарий к строчке
```

Насчёт сбалансированных выражений, то для Scheme работает следующий синтаксис:

```
#;(здесь код парсится
    но (не выполняется))
```

Для Common Lisp не знаю работает ли такой синтаксис, нет под рукой компилятора. Скорее всего нет.

**UPD**: В CL можно поступить так:

```
(defmacro custom-comment (&rest rest)
  nil)

(custom-comment 1 "1" 2 3 (let ()) x) ; ok
```

Попробуйте один из способов, возможно сработает (Нет Emacs Lisp с собой чтобы проверить)

Comment: @Хешкод, а есть ли возможность явно указывать тип кода для подсветки? Или указывать не подсвечивать никак? А то тут всё неправильно выделено.

Comment: Это понятно.
Хочется defun comment , чтобы можно было нарисовать:
(comment всё 
   что угодно , ну может быть скобки и кавычки сбалансированы
)

Comment: Хы, тогда тут нужно просто определить макрос, который ничего не делает с аргументами и всё =) (ну может NIL возврашает для порядку).
<pre>
(defmacro custom-comment (&rest rest)
    nil)

(custom-comment 1 "1" 2 3 (let ()) x) ; ok
</pre>

но код такого вида не работает, т.к. quasiquotation раскрывается на этапе чтения:
<pre>
(custom-comment " sdfsdf " 'x moped `x ,x)
</pre>

Comment: чёрт, я всё про Scheme да CL, а тут же Emacs. Не увидел.

Тогда фиг знает сработает макрос или нет.

Comment: Огромное спасибо !!!
Макрос custtom-comment работает, именно макрос, а я пытался сделать defun

Comment: @Vladimir VG Есть возможность указать язык явно: для этого надо код обернуть в тэги pre и code, и для тэга pre задать нужный класс, например, для lisp: class="prettyprint lang-lisp". Но реально это не нужно: скрипт сам определяет язык. Если язык определился неправильно, то либо кода мало, либо мы не добавили его поддержку (язык редкий). Сейчас lisp'а нет.

Comment: @Хешкод, а где можно узнать список поддерживаемых языков?

Comment: @Vladimir VG Мы добавим список в справку.